# Threading Tkinter with progress bar

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter, queue

I'm trying to make a threaded Tkinter app which uploads video to server, problem is that when I make threaded app, it ends in infinite loop. Here's the code:

```
class ThreadedTask(threading.Thread):
print "threaded task start"
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
    def start_upload(self):
        PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),     "upload_video_to_server.py"))
        if os.path.isfile(PATH) and os.access(PATH, os.R_OK):
           print filename
           upload_video_to_server.make_Info(filename=filename,     title=video_title, description=video_desc, tags=video_keywords)
           upload_video_to_server.upload_Start(filename=filename)
           print "ok"
        else:
            tkMessageBox.showerror(
                "Error!",
                "Unable to find upload script!"
            )
            return

def tb_click():
    print "tbclick start"
    progress()
    prog_bar.start()
    global queue
    queue = Queue.Queue()
    ThreadedTask(queue).start()
    app.after(100, process_queue)

def process_queue():
        try:
            print "try pass"
            msg = queue.get(0)
            print "MSG: ", msg
            prog_bar.stop()
        except Queue.Empty:
            print "Queue is empty!"
            app.after(100, process_queue)

def progress():
    global prog_bar
    print "prog bar is being made"
    prog_bar = ttk.Progressbar(
            app, orient="horizontal",
            length=200, mode="indeterminate"
            )
    prog_bar.pack(side=TOP)

button1 = Button(app, text="START", width=20, command=tb_click)
button1.place(x=355, y=420)
app.mainloop()
```

After running this code, I immediately get "threaded task start" printed out, and upon clicking "START" button I get into infinite loop printing "try pass" and "Queue is empty"... Just nothing (visible to end-user) happens when I click start button (video upload script isn't being run from this code)

What's wrong with this code? Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `start_upload` is never being executed. Try renaming it to `run`. Then it will be executed when `start()` is called.

You'll probably still get "Queue is empty" messages though, because you don't appear to ever add anything to the queue.